# How to retrieve grouped information for this table, using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like this

[image: Table image]

the column `date` contains different dates in the range (2015-2009). Is it possible to use one query to retrieve data like this?

[image: Array image]

Here [2015] - is year that has an array. [01]=>'12', [01] os the month and 12 number of articles in this month i.e.

Comment: in 2nd img what is 12,30, 10 and those keys ??

Comment: The value is the id of the table?

Comment: They are counts for each month in that year

Comment: 12,30 10 those a number of rows (number of news  in the aprticulat month  -- [01] january)

Comment: Well you wont ever retrieve a 3D object from a SQL query. SQL will always return a flat table. You can however do formatting using PHP to achieved the desired output. However, I can't help you unless you provide a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Assuming this site can format cyrillic, can you just paste text instead of images. Cheers (Nastrovie).

Comment: What is the type of the date field? Is it date or string?

Comment: Cone: we tend to discourage the use of images here unless it is necessary (and for data, it is not). You can export data in MySQL as text very easily in phpMyAdmin - both kinds of output can be formatted as code (paste it into the question, select it, click the 'code' button).

Answer (score 0):

Provided the `date` field is actually a date, this should work:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT date_format(`date`, \"%Y-%m\") as YearMonth, count(*) as cnt " .
       "FROM someTable " .
       "GROUP BY YearMonth " .
       "ORDER BY YearMonth ";

$data = array();

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $currentYear = "";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rowYear = substr($row["YearMonth"], 0, 4);
        $rowMonth = substr($row["YearMonth"], 5, 2);
        if ($rowYear != $currentYear) {
            $currentYear = $rowYear;
            $data[$currentYear] = array();
        }
        $data[$currentYear][$rowMonth] = $row["cnt"];
    }
}

$conn->close();

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx you all, I found a solution to my question, here is the query

```
str = "SELECT YEAR(date) AS year,MONTH(date) AS month,count(url) AS qtt  FROM news GROUP BY date_format(date,'%Y-%m');";
```

the array $data  looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2009
            [month] => 12
            [qtt] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2010
            [month] => 1
            [qtt] => 31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2010
            [month] => 2
            [qtt] => 13
        )
)
```

Then I use foreach loop to convert to a needed array

```
   $group = array();

    foreach ($data as $value ) {
        $group[$value['year']][$value['month']] = $value['qtt'];
    }
```

The result is

```
Array
(
    [2009] => Array
        (
            [12] => 7
        )

    [2010] => Array
        (
            [1] => 31
            [2] => 13
            [11] => 15
            [12] => 24
        )

    [2011] => Array
        (
            [9] => 22
            [10] => 31
            [11] => 15
        )

    [2012] => Array
        (
            [7] => 12
            [8] => 31
            [9] => 8
        )
)
```

This is what I needed,
Each array has year as its name that contains an array which has months as keys and number of sposts in this month as values